# Custom build of arduino on a pcb

Tags: arduino-uno-smd

I am running my Arduino based from the ATMEGA328P-PU chip from a 4v battery with this setup:

[image]

Everything works great and now I will like to make my project permanent building a custom PCB from easyeda.com. Anyways this question is not about how to create the custom PCB I have already made one and it works great. This is the PCB that I created:

[image]

Because I liked it so much now I want to build it even better. For example now I will like to combine the crystal with the 22pf ceramic capacitors into one small part.

**Question**

Can I use [----THIS----](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/New-Arrivals_XTY-7325-1600A2210-00_C389842.html) part instead of the basic 22pf capacitor and the big 16Mhz crystal? In other words I want to replace the left picture with the right picture:

[image]

If its possible to use part [7325-1600A2210-00](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/New-Arrivals_XTY-7325-1600A2210-00_C389842.html) then where can I find information on what pins to connect to the atmega328 chip and what pins to connect to ground? 7325-1600A2210-00 has 4 pins. To me it makes sense to connect 2 of the pins to pins 9 and 10 and the other 2 pins to ground. Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use ----THIS---- part instead of the basic 22pf capacitor and the big 16Mhz crystal?

No. That is just a crystal. You still need the capacitors.  If you want a single device then you need a *ceramic resonator*.

Also you're lacking any decoupling capacitors in your circuit. You may find it works for now, but it will become flaky when you start getting it to do things.